# I want to use StartRecordingToFileAsync function in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I want to record screen audio using AppRecordingManager in UWP.

I found StartRecordingToFileAsync function in AppRecordingManager Class to write audio and video content in UWP.

Here is the official document URL about this function:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.apprecording.apprecordingmanager.startrecordingtofileasync#Windows_Media_AppRecording_AppRecordingManager_StartRecordingToFileAsync_Windows_Storage_StorageFile_

Although I try to use this function to record audio, I always keep getting this error: 
The request is invalid in the current state. (Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00D36B2)

I can not find solution for StartRecordingToFileAsync.

How can I solve this error?

Here is my c# code giving me this error.

```
AppRecordingManager manager = AppRecordingManager.GetDefault();
var status = manager.GetStatus();
if (status.CanRecord || status.CanRecordTimeSpan)
{

    var myVideo = await Windows.Storage.StorageLibrary.GetLibraryAsync(Windows.Storage.KnownLibraryId.Videos);
    StorageFolder projectFolder = await myVideo.SaveFolder.CreateFolderAsync("DataFolder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

    var audio = await projectFolder.CreateFileAsync("audio_record.wav", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

    var result = await manager.StartRecordingToFileAsync(audio);

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(result.Succeeded);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(result.ExtendedError.Message);
    }



}
```

Comment: I don't see where you choose a format (video, audio, or both, and the encoding).  The recording manager is not going to look at the filename of the stream you pass to it.

Comment: Could you tell me how to choose a format you mention? I can not find the way by just checking official document.

Comment: Have you add video library capability ?

Comment: Yes,I have already added video capability. But it still does not work.

Comment: Well, I will create a blank app test with above code, if you have sample project, please provide us.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to reproduce same error with your code.

But when I changed "audio_record.wav" to "audio_record.mp4" it worked and it saved video to specified location.

Since [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.apprecording.apprecordingmanager.startrecordingtofileasync#Windows_Media_AppRecording_AppRecordingManager_StartRecordingToFileAsync_Windows_Storage_StorageFile_) states that StartRecordingToFileAsync "Writes audio and video content of the current app" it's possible that you can't save just audio using that method.